# Kodi and vainfo crash

Tags: kodi

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 on a Intel NUC7PJYH with i965 vaapi driver.
Since a few days, kodi crashes with a segfault while starting. I.e. starting kodi the screens gets black and kodi crashes before the GUI appears. The kodi log does not contain anything special. Since kodi writes a line about vainfo before the crash, I ran vainfo and it crashed also with a segfault, without more info. strace kodi does also show nothing special. Going back 2 kernel versions did not help. I think the problem came with an update of one of the packets. What can I do to find out more?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: in /usr/local/lib was a second set of libva and i965 drivers. After deleting /usr/local/lib, problem was solved.